# MVP Presenter not injected correctly

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am learning Kotlin and Dagger 2 simultaneously by attempting to convert some of [Mindorks advanced MVP sample](https://github.com/MindorksOpenSource/android-mvp-interactor-architecture) to Kotlin but am having Dagger2 compile issues. I am swimming in classes here but am very close! Don't mind the untidiness, I intend to comb over each class once it compiles. If something is missing please let me know. The error comes down to my presenter class not being correctly injected into the activity. The error reads as follows:

```
e: D:\_Dev\repo\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\com\xxx\di\component\ActivityComponent.java:8: error: com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Presenter<com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.View,? extends com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Interactor> cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
e: 

e:     public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                          ^
e:       com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Presenter<com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.View,? extends com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Interactor> is injected at
e:           com.xxx.login.LoginActivity.presenter
e:       com.xxx.login.LoginActivity is injected at
e:           com.xxx.di.component.ActivityComponent.inject(activity)
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
```

**EDIT:**

[Here is a repo with the failing code](https://github.com/danielwilson1702/mindorks-kotlin-sample), built with the latest canary build of Android Studio

BaseActivity.kt

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MvpView {

    val activityComponent: ActivityComponent by lazy {
        DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
                .applicationComponent((application as App).applicationComponent)
                .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
                .build()
    }
}
```

BasePresenter.kt

```
open class BasePresenter<V : MvpView, out I: MvpInteractor>
@Inject constructor(private val mvpInteractor: I) : MvpPresenter<V, I> {

    private var mvpView: V? = null

    override fun onAttach(mvpView: V) {
        this.mvpView = mvpView
    }

    override fun onDetach() {
        mvpView = null
    }

    override fun getMvpView(): V? {
        return mvpView
    }

    override fun getInteractor(): I {
        return mvpInteractor
    }

}
```

MvpPresenter.kt (MvpView and MvpInteractor are basic empty interfaces)

```
interface MvpPresenter<V: MvpView, out I: MvpInteractor> {

    fun onAttach(mvpView: V)

    fun onDetach()

    fun getMvpView(): V?

    fun getInteractor(): I
}
```

App.kt

```
class App: Application() {

    lateinit var applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        applicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this)).build()

        applicationComponent.inject(this)
    }

    fun getComponent(): ApplicationComponent {
        return applicationComponent
    }

    fun setComponent(applicationComponent: ApplicationComponent) {
        this.applicationComponent = applicationComponent
    }
}
```

ApplicationComponent.kt

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {

    fun inject(app: App)

    @ApplicationContext fun context(): Context

    fun application(): Application

    //Pref helper
    //Api helper
}
```

ApplicationModule.kt

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    fun provideContext(): Context = application

    @Provides
    fun provideApplication(): Application = application

    //Provide api helper

    //Provide pref helper

    //Provide api key etc.
}
```

ActivityModule.kt

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(val activity: AppCompatActivity) {

    @Provides
    fun provideContext(): Context = activity

    @Provides
    fun provideActivity(): AppCompatActivity = activity

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginPresenter(presenter: LoginPresenter<LoginMVP.View, LoginMVP.Interactor>):
            LoginMVP.Presenter<LoginMVP.View, LoginMVP.Interactor> {
        return presenter
    }

    @Provides
    fun provideLoginMvpInteractor(interactor: LoginInteractor):
            LoginMVP.Interactor {
        return interactor
    }

}
```

ActivityComponent.kt

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class), modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class))
interface ActivityComponent {

    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)
}
```

LoginActivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : BaseActivity(), LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>, LoginMVP.View {

    @Inject lateinit var presenter: LoginMVP.Presenter<LoginMVP.View, LoginMVP.Interactor>

    private var authTask: UserLoginTask? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login)

        activityComponent.inject(this)

        email_sign_in_button.setOnClickListener { presenter.onServerLoginClick(email.text.toString(), password.text.toString()) }

        presenter.onAttach(this)
    }
}
```

LoginMVP.kt

```
interface LoginMVP {

    interface Interactor : MvpInteractor {

    }

    @PerActivity
    interface Presenter<V : LoginMVP.View, out I : LoginMVP.Interactor>
        : MvpPresenter<V, I> {

        fun onServerLoginClick(email: String, password: String)

    }

    interface View : MvpView {
        fun openMainActivity()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind pushing your current state to Github? Would like to have a look.

Comment: Thanks @Ascorbin , I've added a repo link now. It is built with the latest canary Android Studio so hopefully that ain't a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a full answer but pretty close.

Problem is in`out` modifier. With this modifier Dagger try inject

```
com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Presenter<com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.View,? extends com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Interactor>
```

but you provide only

```
  com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Presenter<com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.View, com.xxx.login.LoginMVP.Interactor>
```

(in function `provideLoginPresenter`).

So if remove all `out` modifies (from `Presenter`, `BasePresenter`, `LoginPresenter`) it starts compile and work.

I'm not sure why Dagger try inject wrong type or cannot understand that it is same type. It looks like bug while annotation processing. So the simplest solution - don't use `out` modifier
with Dagger.

Comment: Well done thanks for that. I just did what AS told me to and it caused me about 6 hours of grief :)